# Adding selectableItemBackground and also coloring background

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have added the selectableItemBackground on CardView that displays on recyclerview.
each CardView show text and image.
each Card is can be selected, and in order to add ripple effect when clicked I have added:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

The problem is that now I cant set the background color. those two lines together show an error:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

How can I color the layout background and also add the ripple effect with selectableItemBackground.

complete card_view.xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--CANT ADD THIS: android:background="#FFFFFF"-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/singleTextLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/singleImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="3dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is that I can't color the background in white while combining the ?attr/selectableItemBackground for ripple effect and then it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: have you tried selector ?

Comment: Ill check it out thanks

Comment: has anyone has answer to this question @RahulSharma

Comment: במקום להוסיף את זה בתור `background`

תוסיף אותו בתור `foreground`

ככה:
android:background="#ffffff"
android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score 16):

You have 2 options:

**1: Add parent linear layout:**

*parent layout* has backgroundcolor and
*child layout* has ripple efect

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/singleTextLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/singleImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="3dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**2 : Opton:**
Create drawable resource:bg_ripple.xml

one in folder **drawable**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

another in folder **drawable-v21**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/gray">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</ripple>
```

Then set as background this resource to your layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_ripple"
```

Comment: Does the first option provide a ripple effect on pre API 21 devices ?? That is, Android 4.x,x

Answer (score 4):

Now we can achieve this in a better way.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" //ACTUAL BACKGROUND
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground" //RIPPLE EFFECT
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: This worked way easy as compared to other solutions

Comment: This is good but only applicable for API 23+

Comment: My app still supports Android 4.0, so I can't actually use this

Comment: Did you try @Matej Scolopax answer?

Answer (score 1):

one more easy way is that put one more FrameLayout(setting background color) and includes original TextView

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/category_numbers">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/category_numbers" />
</FrameLayout>
```